# publish story using Object API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish stories from my server when people win a game into my web app.

I have folowed [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/) but i apparently do something wrong, here is the url and the datas object i pass into my POST call.

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/'+user_id+'/points.win

    var Datas = { 
        title: '500', 
        type: 'mygame:points',
        image: 'http://mywebsite.jpg', 
        url: 'https://mywebsite.com',
        description: 'YOU WIN !',
        data: { rank: 326 },
        'points': OBJECT_ID, 
        'access_token': TOKEN 
    };
```

I get the error: `{"message":"Unknown path components: \/points.win","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}`

I do have a "Points" object and a "Win" action on my app interface (and a "Win A Point" story). 
I don't really know what i am doing wrong, also i am not sure my OBJECT_ID is right, i found a value close to my `app_id` at the end of the sample url by clicking "Get the Code" (on the `points` object) > Code for object > inside the `object=...url=.../<here>...` and i used it here but i didn't find where it's clearly said `Object_id: <value>` on developer.facebook.com.

**UPDATE:** I think the only way to get an `object ID` is to create it thought the `Object API`, i am going to try this way, i'll keep you updated if it's works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the object through the `Object API` and it works fine !